# Unable to DROP a MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I need to drop a deprecated, empty table from my MySQL Database.

The table definition is noddy:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Address` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ContactId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `ContactId` (`ContactId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

This results in

`#1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`

There was a constraint on ContactId but II've removed it.

PHPMyAdmin's export function doesn't show anything beyond the table definition shown above. There are no rows in the table and, to my knowledge, no FKs reference the `Address.Id` field (But I don't know how to verify this).

Can someone please advise how I can get rid of the table?

Comment: do you have another table that refer with foreign key to Address?

Comment: @Kokers as per the question, not that I know of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To list foreign keys

```
select 
    concat(table_name, '.', column_name) as 'foreign key',  
    concat(referenced_table_name, '.', referenced_column_name) as 'references'
from
    information_schema.key_column_usage
where
    referenced_table_name is not null;
```

For specifc search in your case:

```
select 
    constraint_name
from
    information_schema.key_column_usage
where
    referenced_table_name = 'Address' AND referenced_column_name = 'ContactId';
```

To drop a foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name] DROP FOREIGN KEY [constraint_name];
```

Comment: This shows an entry for "Address.ContactId - Contact.Id" which makes me think the FK still exists. How can I nuke it?

Comment: does your contact table show a FK relationship to address?  What I'm getting at is there are two sides to the key, the source table and child table, maybe for some reason one of the two didn't get removed when you got rid of the original..

Comment: Then I guess it indeed still exists. Modified my answer a bit.

Comment: Thanks, that gave me enouhg info to track it down - There was an FK pointing at the wrong index from a table I just created.

Answer (score 13):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
DROP TABLE Address;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: While this works, its risky, as the system still think's theres a FK relationship; better to resolve that and ONLY use this if you KNOW no tables have a FK to it.

Comment: Thank you... I'm sure this would work but I'm cautious about just ignoring the constraints as it might break referential integrity (at least, as I understand it). Because of that, I'd prefer to fix the underlying problem before I try the sledgehammer.