# MySQL - attempting to drop one side of a one-to-one relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm in the midst of modifying my current DB schema.  I'd like to drop the child side of a one-to-one relationship, but I keep getting SQL errors about the foreign key restraint, specifically:

> #1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Even though there doesn't seem to be any foreign key in play at the moment (the child table is completely empty).

Any ideas?

Comment: But it sounds like there's another table which depends on the table you're trying to drop (FK defined in the 3rd table). Check the key definitions in all your other tables.

Comment: What statement are you trying to execute specifically? Is this a `DROP TABLE` or `DELETE FROM`?

Comment: DROP TABLE.  The child table is empty.

Comment: It would be nice if the error message actually referred to the table and/or key :-/

Comment: I don't think it matters that the table is empty. There is some other table that references the table you are trying to drop. SQL Server does the same thing. Like I have 2 tables and both are empty but one references the other. I can't drop the referenced table without first removing the other.

Comment: There *was* a third table, but I was (amazingly) able to drop that table, even though it was a join/pivot table between the child and another table.  So, now there's *just* the parent and child, and the error remains.  Which is odd

Comment: drop the constraint and then try dropping the table.

Comment: Mind giving me the syntax to do so?  SQL is definitely not where my skills lie.  I know the basics, but not how to manipulate tables in that manner

Comment: @KevinM1 you can try `SELECT * FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'yourTable'` and see if there are other tables that reference the one you are trying to drop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, DROP the foreign key constraint from the referencing (child) table, and then DROP the referenced  (parent) table.

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE child
  DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_child_parent ;

DROP TABLE parent ;
```

(Obviously, you'd need to replace the "child", "parent" and "FK_child_parent" with the actual identifiers for your tables and foreign key constraint.

One easy way to get the name of the foreign key constraint is to use the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statement,

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE child ;
```

The output from that will show the name of the foreign key constraint.

If you don't know which tables have a foreign key referencing the table, you can query the `information_schema.referential_constraints` table to find them

```
WHERE referenced_table_name = 'parent'
  AND constraint_schema = 'mydatabase'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
//Do your drop statement
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

?

Comment: Thanks jww, KevinM1 you can find an answer here, this guy has the same problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182871/unable-to-drop-a-mysql-table)